# Referencing other sheets in loop not working

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hoping someone can help me figure out what's missing from my code. I have a validation list on one sheet, and I'm attempting to loop that list on a different sheet and change the filter on pivot table on that different sheet. The loop works through the validation list if I run the macro on the sheet with that validation cell, but on the sheet with my pivot table it only loops through the cells on that sheet. Consequently, if I'm on the sheet with the validation list, the loop works correctly through that validation list, but the pivot table filter doesn't change. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't figure out what it is.  Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Addvalidationlist() ' there's no problems with this macro, not the most elegant code but it works


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim lastline As Long, newlastline As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("qry_FB_forecast_file_NEW")

With sh1

lastline = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Set rng = sh1.Range("H1:H" & lastline)
rng.Copy Range("X:X")

sh1.Range("X:X").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
newlastline = sh1.Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng2 = sh1.Range("X2:X" & newlastline)

Set rng3 = sh1.Range("Y1")

With rng3.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='" & sh1.Name & "'!" & rng2.Address
    
End With



End With

' end of validation list sub
```

```
**Public Sub exportbybrand()** *This is the one I'm having trouble with *

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim lastline As Long, newlastline As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range

Dim valcell As Range
Dim valcellsource As Range
Dim Family As String


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets("qry_FB_forecast_file_NEW")


Set valcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("qry_FB_forecast_file_NEW").Range("Y1")

Set valcellsource = Evaluate(valcell.Validation.Formula1)

Set sh2 = wb.Worksheets("MR Front Edit")

On Error Resume Next

With sh1

For Each valcell In valcellsource
    valcell.Value = valcell.Value
    Family = valcell
    
    MsgBox Family
    
        With sh2
    
        
        sh1.PivotTables("PivotTable1") _
        .PivotFields("FamilyId").CurrentPage = Family
        End With
Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Step 1: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and see what errors might be happening. That line should be used only in rare cases.

Comment: Hi! I did do that and it gives a Run-time error '1004': Method 'PivotTables' of object'_Worksheet' failed. I'm pretty sure it's because the variable "valcell" is empty when I run the macro on the "MR Front Edit" worksheet. I have a Msgbox prompt showing me the value of that cell before it attempts to filter the pivot table. When I'm running the macro on the sheet with the validation list ("qry_FB_forecast_file_NEW"), that Msgbox is showing the correct values in the validation list.